# mysterious values as output in vector R using if and else

Tags: r, for-loop, compare, if-statement

I have a vector of values (numbers only).  I want to split up this vector into two vectors.  One vector will contain values less than the average of the original vector, the other will contain values more than the average of the original vector.  I have the following as a test R script:

```
v <- c(1,1,4,6,3,67,10,194,847)

#Initialize
v.in<- c(rep(0),length(v))
v.out<- c(rep(0),length(v))

for (i in 1:length(v))
{
   if (v < 0.68 * mean(v))
   {
      v.in[i] <- v[i]
   }
   else
   {
      v.out[i] <- v[i]
   }
}
v.in
v.out

## <https://gist.github.com/8a6747ea9b7421161c43>
```

I get the following result:

```
9: In if (v < 0.68 * mean(v)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
> v.in
[1]   1   1   4   6   3  67  10 194 847
> v.out
[1] 0 9
> v
[1]   1   1   4   6   3  67  10 194 847
>
```

Clearly, 0 and 9 are not values of any of the elements in v.

Any suggestions what is going on and how to fix this?

Thanks,
Ed

Comment: change your condition to `(v[i] < 0.68 * mean(v))` (ie. use `v[i]` rather than `v` on the left of the inequality)

Comment: also `c(rep(0),length(v))` should be `rep(0, length(v))`

Comment: and you are using an indentation style that is in general not compatible with R. See the "unexpected else" section of http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf for a good explanation.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I replaced the condition with if(v[i] < 0.68 * mean(v)) but still getting 0 9 NA NA NA NA NA NA 194 847.  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@BenBolker pointed out in the comment why you code doesn't work: you need to select a single element from `v` when using `if`. However, you might find `split` a better function for a task like this:

```
split(v,v<0.68*mean(v))
$`FALSE`
[1] 194 847

$`TRUE`
[1]  1  1  4  6  3 67 10
```

The answer to the mystery of `v.out` is that its branch doesn't get selected so it doesn't get changed. It therefore retains its inital value, which is (presumably) erroneously given the value of a single `0` and the length of the vector (`9`) rather than nine copies of zero as I suspect you intended.

Comment: Thanks James!  Quick and easy solution.